# Custom Function Add-in using Typescript Modules

Tags: office-js

I have developed my Add-In using Typescript and splitting the code into modules. This has worked fine so far. I have created a task pane and a command. These have both allowed for the import of code from other modules. However I have now started with the custom function and as soon as I include an import in the main custom function code the Add-In no longer runs. I have tested this with a simple example with and without an import. The task pane won't open. It gets stuck on a loading message and the custom function does not resolve.

```js
import { someText } from "./constants.js";

/**
 * Adds two numbers.
 * @customfunction
 * @param first First number
 * @param second Second number
 * @returns The sum of the two numbers.
 */
function add(first: number, second: number) {
  console.log(someText);
  return first + second;
}

CustomFunctions.associate("ADD", add);
```

Without the import (and the console log) it works fine.

I have not found much searching for this issue. One old post referred to support for a shared runtime maybe being a solution for including external Javascript but that has not helped me.

So I am really trying to confirm whether this is in fact supported or does one need to bundle the code using something like WebPack and not have the target output code in modules?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my shared runtime configuration was not 100% correct and seems that this is in fact supported.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).